# I need write a method that returns the name of the country with the most number of gold than bronze then silver medals

Tags: java

*I need to write a method that returns the name of the country with the most number of gold than bronze then silver medals. This is how I did for gold medals but how to convert to the method that gonna execute for others just stack.*

```
    List<String> countryName = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> goldMedal = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    Iterator<String> i1 = countryName.iterator();
    Iterator<Integer> i2 = goldMedal.iterator();

    while (i1.hasNext() && i2.hasNext()) {
        map.put(i1.next(), i2.next());
    }
    if (i1.hasNext() || i2.hasNext());

    Entry<String, Integer> maxEntry = null;
    for (Entry<String, Integer> entry  : map.entrySet()) {
        if (maxEntry == null || entry.getValue().compareTo(maxEntry.getValue()) > 0)
        {
            maxEntry = entry;
        }

    }
```

Comment: replace `goldMedal` with `bronzeMedal` and you're done

Comment: first create a good data structure to store your input. Also note that there can be more than one country that has the max number of golds, silvers and bronzes.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, There is no need to create a `Map` just to find the country with the most medals:

```
    List<String> countryName = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> goldMedal = new ArrayList<>();
    Integer maxMedals = goldMedal.stream().max(Integer::compareTo).get();
    int maxMedalsIdx = IntStream.range(0, goldMedal.size())
            .filter(i -> goldMedal.get(i).equals(maxMedals))
            .findFirst().getAsInt();
    countryName.get(maxMedalsIdx);  // your answer
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use comparator chaining for this.

You can implement comparator chain by yourself http://www.codejava.net/java-core/collections/sorting-a-list-by-multiple-attributes-example.

You can use already implemented comparator chain class https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-2.1.1/org/apache/commons/collections/comparators/ComparatorChain.html

Comment: Posting links here helps but taking what is necessary from the links and writing answers better answers the question. Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)